# How to run application using SMS from another phone?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, sms

I want to run an application on another mobile without any external interaction using SMS from another mobile. Is that possible, and how to do that?

No, I don't want to the user to open the SMS and launch the application, no point of it then, I wan't something like remote motor operating using SMS.

Any ideas?

Can we send SMS from any CDMA/GSM mobiles to a particular port for another mobile?

Comment: Making a J2ME application that is, for all intents and purposes, invisible to the user may require using non-standard APIs and configurations that could require your application be signed by the handset manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [WMA push](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=120) it can be possible. Please see [MIDP 2.0 Push Registry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/) article to understand what is push and how to use it.

Comment: how to get the port for the SMS?

Comment: You get the port on mobile phone SMS just like you would any desktop socket: either hardcode it and risk it being already used or try a range of ports until you find one that works and communicate it to a remote central repository.

Comment: @QuickRecipesOnSymbianOS Hi, can I also send SMS to another mobile at that port to which I binded.

Comment: Once you have a "server" MIDlet on a phone bound to one of its own local port, any other phone can send SMS to that port. Look at the WMA example code.